# How to set up Hibernate composite key table in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How do I set up the following in Hibernate?

I have a table named "Address" to hold a person or company address. I want to create a Keyword table where I can put some searchable values 
to associate with the address like "plumber" or "mowing service". To make the association I create a third table "KeywordInstance" which 
has a composite key and only has the keys to the specific address entry and a keyword entry.

So there could be zero or more entries in "KeywordInstance" for an address. I am unsure how to set this up in Hibernate.

```
    create table Address (
      AddressId         INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

      (other fields)

      PRIMARY KEY(AddressId)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;

    create table Keywords (
      Id            INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      Keyword       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      PRIMARY KEY(Id)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;

    create table KeywordInstance (
      KeywordKey    INTEGER NOT NULL,
      AddressId    INTEGER NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(KeywordKey,AddressId)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;




    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Address", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "AddressId" }) })
    public class AddressDTO implements Comparable, Serializable
    {
        @Transient
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 43L;


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "AddressId", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer addressId;

        @Column(name = "FirstName", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 50)
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "MiddleName", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 50)
        private String middleName;

        @Column(name = "LastName", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 50)
        private String lastName;

        @Column(name = "Addr1", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 100)
        private String addr1;

        @Column(name = "Addr2", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 100)
        private String addr2;

        @Column(name = "City", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 50)
        private String city;

        @Column(name = "State", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 2)
        private String state;

        @Column(name = "Zip", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 10)
        private String zip;

        @Column(name = "Spouse", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 50)
        private String spouse;

        @Column(name = "Company", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 80)
        private String company;

        @Column(name = "Website", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 180)
        private String website;

        @Lob
        @Column(name = "Notes", unique = false, nullable = true)
        private String notes;

        @Column(name = "Type", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 1)
        private String addressType;

        (getters, setters)
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Keywords", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "Id" }) })
    public class KeywordDTO implements Serializable
    {
        @Transient
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 46L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(table = "Keywords", name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
        private Integer id;

        @Column(table = "Keywords", name = "Keyword", unique = true, length = 100)
        private String keyword;

        (getters, setters)
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "KeywordInstance")
    public class KeywordInstanceDTO implements Serializable
    {
        @Transient
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 49L;

        private Integer keywordKey;

        private Integer addressId;

        (getters, setter)
    }
```

Comment: you may want to try `@Embeddable` and `@EmbededId`.